# Prestashop 1.6. auto-clean stats

Tags: statistics, prestashop

where I can find setting of auto-clean statistics in Prestashop 1.6.? In 1.5. it was in

> "Stats" -> "Settings" -> "Auto-clean period"

There are 3 options (Week, Month, Year), but in 1.6. I can´t found these options.

Answer (score 1):

**This option do not exists in the new versions of the PrestaShop but there is a good module for stats cleaning:**

Automatic Stats Cleaner Module allows you to clear stats data that are collected by your store and take very huge space in database. It may reduce store database up to 90% depending on how long you have been running your store.

**Compatible with PrestaShop v1.5 - v1.7.5**

- allow to delete statistics from connections
- allow to delete statistics from logs
- allow to delete statistics from not found pages
- allow to delete statistics from guest information
- allow to delete collection of no needed shopping cart data
- allow to set up automatic stats cleaning

**Here you can find this module:** 
https://addons.prestashop.com/en/website-performance/43071-automatic-stats-cleaner.html

**Don't forget to make backup of the database before first cleaning.**

Answer (score -1):

Using the free add-on "**PrestaShop Cleaner**" in Prestashop 1.6.x you can clean your database of clients and orders. That will clean your statistics as well.

Don't forget to **make Backups** before doing that.

Comment: Could not find that module by searching, please give a link to the module.

Comment: using the "cleaner" module is not a good suggestion, it would remove eveything from the store

Comment: @jCloud I know it's probably too late, but there is now a git hub version of the module under: https://github.com/PrestaShop/pscleaner.

Comment: I found another module for cleaning stats: https://addons.prestashop.com/en/product.php?id_product=22344

Comment: @jCould I haven't tried the other option but it seems good. Have you tried it?